# How can I store Objects in cassandra using the blob datatype

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I tried with the data type `blob`. That's giving some Datastax exception. I tried the object itself, bytearray. Still no good:

```
 Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid STRING constant ([B@547248ad) for user_object of type blob
```

This is the failing INSERT:

```
executeSting.append("INSERT INTO htadb.objecttable (object_id, bucket_name, object_key, link, user_status, user_object) ")
            .append("VALUES (")
            .append(objectId).append(",'")
            .append(bucketName).append("','")
            .append(key).append("','")
            .append(link).append("','")
            .append("online").append("','")
            .append(serializer(register)).append("')"
                    + ";");
```

Comment: There's an example of how to store images in C* on [DataStax's github](https://github.com/datastax/code-samples/tree/master/blobs_java_driver/src/main/java).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From documentation

```
blob  | blobs  |  Arbitrary bytes (no validation), expressed as hexadecimal
```

so what you need is provided by the [Bytes](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/Bytes.html) class. The following is an interface I use to serialize/deserialize Java objects I need to save in Cassandra

```
public interface Bufferable extends Serializable {

    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bufferable.class);

    default ByteBuffer serialize() {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bytes);) {
            oos.writeObject(this);
            String hexString = Bytes.toHexString(bytes.toByteArray());
            return Bytes.fromHexString(hexString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Serializing bufferable object error", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Bufferable deserialize(ByteBuffer bytes) {
        String hx = Bytes.toHexString(bytes);
        ByteBuffer ex = Bytes.fromHexString(hx);
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(ex.array()));) {
            return (Bufferable) ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Deserializing bufferable object error", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks for the answer Carlo, i used the above code still i m getting the same exception Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid STRING constant ([B@547248ad) for user_object of type blob
. I think its my query error. adding my query code please check

Comment: I don't understand your query -- using a boundstatement you should invoke setBytes() on your BS passing the ByteBuffer

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Array[Byte]` object using `java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cassandra 4's ByteUtils](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.4/index.html?com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/data/ByteUtils.html)
Super easy. For example you can use ByteUtils.toHexString(bytes).